# Aggregating administrative boundaries using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve, aggregate

I am working with a shapefile with polygons at the state level which I am grouping using the dissolve tool.

How can I save the resulting layers produced from the several dissolve output layers into one layer that retains the new aggregated properties of the regions?

Merging does not retain the new boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the tool you're looking for is **Append**. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm

This will add the multiple layers into one shapefile. 
There is some discussion [here](https://community.esri.com/groups/technical-support/blog/2014/12/02/combining-spatial-data-in-arcmap) on the differences between merge, union and append that may be useful to you as well!